# "New answer has been posted" not appearing

Tags: bug, user-interface

A few days ago, the yellow bar that says "new answer has been posted" stopped showing. Thrice I've posted an answer that was almost the same as an answer that was posted, because I went to do some research and testing of my solution. This led to a few down votes and ultimately the deletion of my answer. It was working fine before, and on searches the "1 new question has been posted" and when on questions the "1 new answer/comment has been posted" works, but not when making an answer. I am on IE11 (The latest, version 11.0.9600.17498) on Windows 8.1 (64-bit).

Comment: The bar does appear for me in IE 11 / windows 7.